# Is there any other way to declare global variable in Extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I tried declaring global variable in **ExtJs4.2** version as shown below.

```
Ext.application({
    globals: {
        praticalsValue: []
    },
    requires: ['MyApp.util.Utilities'] //Don't forget to require your class
});
```

1. issue I am facing is getting console error

   http://localhost:8080/sample-webapp/MyApp/util/Utilities.js?_dc=1546951098727 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
2. Is there any other way to declare global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You could use [singleton](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-singleton) class in Extjs for you application. When you creating your `Utilities` so inside that you need to set config `singleton:true` When set to true, the class will be instantiated as singleton. For example:

```
Ext.define('Logger', {
    singleton: true,
    log: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});

Logger.log('Hello');
```

You can check here with working [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2ot7) demo. It's just small demo you can implement with your application. And also you can visit here [ExtJS gitlab project with sigletone class utility](https://gitlab.com/njdhv105/ExtJS-GeoLocation/tree/development)

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        //This sigletone class will accesible througout the app via using the
        //Name {AppConstants( whatever name your provide you can access with the same name)}

        //{singleton: true,} When set to true, the class will be instantiated as singleton.
        Ext.define('AppConstants', {
            alternateClassName: 'AppConstants',
            singleton: true,

            config: {
                userId: '1'
            },

            constructor: function (config) {
                this.initConfig(config);
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{

            title: 'Define global variable in singletone class',

            bodyPadding: 15,

            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Set value userId',
                margin: '0 15',
                handler: function () {

                    //we set value using setter of singleton.
                    Ext.Msg.prompt('New value of userId', 'Please enter userId value', function (btn, text) {
                        if (btn == 'ok') {
                            AppConstants.setUserId(text);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Get value userId',
                handler: function () {
                    //we get value using getter of singleton.
                    Ext.Msg.alert('userId value is ', AppConstants.getUserId());
                }
            }],

            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i am new not able to relate into your code...Can you please help  me to understand more.

Y should i use ext.define?

Comment: Ext.application({ singleton:true,
  globals:{
  praticalsValue :[]
  }
});

Comment: Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$application' of undefined

Comment: For [Ext.define](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-define) you can refer the docs. it's Defines a class or override.